# Linked List in RAM memory

Tags: memory, data-structures, memory-management

While i was studying java and data structures, i learned what a LinkedList is and how it can increase it's maximum size even after declared. So i want to know how this works in the memory, does it just skip to the next available slot? For example, if it initially used slots 11, 12 and 13, and i increase it, does it just use the next available slot, for example 19?

This might be pretty dumb, but i was studying c++ and learned some things about how the code interacts with the RAM, and how different types have different bytes that are going to be read, basic stuff. I got confused about how LinkedLists interact with the memory when i learned about it.

Comment: What do you mean by `slots`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually linked list implementation in nutshell looks similar to something like this:

```java
class LinkedList {
    Node head; // head

    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next; // link to the next node
        Node(int d) { 
            data = d; 
        }
    }
}
```

So node class is a [reference type](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-8-pocket/9781491901083/ch04.html) which is stored on [heap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stack-heap) (used for the dynamic memory allocation of Java objects at runtime) so the `Node` instances will be allocated in arbitrary places (determined by the memory allocation algorithm used by the JVM) among other object allocated during app lifetime (I assume you call this "slots") so they will not occupy continuous space in general case (like for example arrays will do <sup>[1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects)</sup>).

---

<sup>[1](https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects)</sup> requires some discussion about [primitive types and objects](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-8-pocket/9781491901083/ch04.html) and what is stored where and how